# How to combine values from different arrays of object into an array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I want to capture the parameter `Unassigned` with value `64314` from the API output. My objective is to capture this information in an array such as `['Unassigned',64314]`

I used this for-in loop to achieve the above.

```
var data = obj.rows;

for(var item in data){

 console.log(data[item].dimensionValues);
 console.log(data[item].metricValues);

}


//Output
[{
  value: "Direct"
}]
[{
  value: 1405211
}]....
```

But I am unable to map it to achieve this `['Unassigned',64314]`. To me it seems I have to further loop the second level

```
//API Output

var obj = {
   "metricHeaders":[
      {
         "name":"sessions",
         "type":"TYPE_INTEGER"
      }
   ],
   "dimensionHeaders":[
      {
         "name":"defaultChannelGroup"
      }
   ],
   "kind":"analyticsData#runReport",
   "rowCount":16.0,
   "rows":[
      {
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":789456
            }
         ],
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"Direct"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"Organic Search"
            }
         ],
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":7894521
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"Paid Search"
            }
         ],
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":789456
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"Cross-network"
            }
         ],
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":1254689
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"Email"
            }
         ],
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":97766
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":53208
            }
         ],
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"Paid Social"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":64314
            }
         ],
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"Unassigned"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":30069
            }
         ],
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"Referral"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":28790
            }
         ],
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"Organic Social"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"Paid Video"
            }
         ],
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":14840
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":11619
            }
         ],
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"Display"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":2165
            }
         ],
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"Organic Video"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":806
            }
         ],
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"Paid Other"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"ABC"
            }
         ],
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":261
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"SMS"
            }
         ],
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":2
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensionValues":[
            {
               "value":"Organic Shopping"
            }
         ],
         "metricValues":[
            {
               "value":1
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "metadata":{
      "currencyCode":"USD",
      "timeZone":"XXXX"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dimentionaValues` & `metricValues` going to have only one item, then you can specify 1st item and create array dynamically?

```
console.log([data[item].dimensionValues[0].value,data[item].metricValues[0].value]);
```

If they are of same length, you need another loop

```
for(var item in data){
  for(var i=0; i< data[item].dimensionValues.length;i++){
 console.log([data[item].dimensionValues[i].value,data[item].metricValues[i].value]);
  }
}
```

If they are of different length, you need to specify what logic in question.

Comment: The second option works. I have a question. You assigned 
```  i < data[item].dimensionValues.length ``` but under the for loop, you are consoling ```data[item].metricValues[i].value``` How come the last part is available under the first part?

Comment: We are considering both having same lenght, so nth value of `dimensionValues` is nth value of `metricValues` as well.